# useEffect called when a variable not in the dependancy list is updated (causing an infinite loop)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm trying to do an ajax call when a state changes, and then set another state to the result of that ajax call.

```js
const [plc, setPlc] = useState(null);
const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

...

useEffect(()=>{
  if(plc != null) {
    myAjaxPromiseFunction(plc).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    }).then((tags)=>{
      setTags(tags);
    });
  }
}, [plc]);
```

For some reason, this results in an infinite loop. However, when I remove the `setTags(tags);` statement it works as expected. It appears that the `setTags` function is causing the effect hook to update, but `tags` is not a part of the dependencies of this effect hook.

FYI, the `tags` variable is supposed to be a list of objects.

**EDIT:**

I have one other `useEffect` in my code.

```js
useEffect(() => { // Update which tags are logged
  if(plc != null) {
    anotherAjaxFunction(plc, tags).catch(err => {
      toaster.show({
        message: err,
        intent: "danger"
      });
    }).then(tags => {
      setTags(tags);
    });
  }
}, [plc, updateLoggedFlag]);
```

However, this `useEffect` is not dependant on `tags`, and the issue still occurs if I remove this block of code.

*Side note:* The `updateLoggedFlag` is a variable I was planning to use to force the effect to update as needed, but I haven't used it anywhere yet.

**Another EDIT:** Link to reproduction using code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-ives-3xyrq?file=/src/App.js

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: don't you have another useEffect on your code? this effect alone won't trigger an infinite loop

Comment: [This wouldn't happen normally](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-cartwright-wefv3?file=/src/App.js). Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I'll have to do some more hunting; I was able to get the "minimal reproducible example" working.

Comment: Can you show the rest of component?

Comment: [Here's a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-ives-3xyrq?file=/src/App.js) with the full component. I'll add it to my original post as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: move `TagColumn` outside of `App`, as it is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-frost-c6ngc).

---

The problem is not connected to the effects declaration, it's due to the component declaration.

In your sandbox, the `TagColumn` was defined inside of `App`. It means that every time `App` was rendered (in particular, every time its state is changed), the `const TagColumn` was assigned a different value. React can't see that it is the same component every time - after all, it's not really the same, since the captured scope is changing.
So, `App` renders a new `TagColumn`. React sees that component is created from scratch, renders it, and, in particular, invokes its hooks, including every `useEffect`. Inside `useEffect`, you use callback to change the state of `App`. `App` rerenders, creates *yet another* component `TagColumn`, which is again rendered for the first time in its life, calling every `useEffect`... and the cycle continues.

In general, you shouldn't capture anything non-constant in the functional component scope. Instead:

- if the value is generated by external context (`App`, in this case) - pass it as props;
- if the value is generated by the component itself - use `useState`, `useRef` or other hooks, as necessary.

Comment: So does this mean the methods wrapped in useEffect should be taken out of TagColumn and moved into App?

Comment: @Luke, I believe @Cerberus meant that the TagColumn component should not be nested inside the App component as a constant variable. If the TagColumn is moved outside the App component, the TabColumn component can be rendered independently from the App. I don't think it matters where the `useEffect` goes in this case.

Comment: That's what I did, and I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think with your code is that it does not include tags in the dependency array. Conceptually, this should work fine, as mentioned before by other developers, but React documentation states that, all the state variables and props used inside the callback, should be present inside the dependency array, otherwise it can cause bugs. Have a look at it here. [Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)

Comment: I added `tags` to the dependency array and rewrote the code so that I was no longer calling `setTags` in the second `useEffect` block. Unfortunately, I'm still getting an infinite loop.